# How do you profile an HTML5 game on iOS?

Tags: ios, html, profiling, memory-profiling

My background is in native game development on Windows. But I'm currently working on an iOS game that's built with HTML5. How do I profile such a game? The typical profiling tools for iOS only tell you about memory as it's used by the native layer. I have no idea what portion of the memory is used by WebView, OpenGL, or the native plugins. I've been scouring the internet, and the best I can find is how to profile HTML5 using Google Chrome, which doesn't help me that much.

I'd appreciate any help.